# Como selecionar valor no Select

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Como selecionar um valor que não seja o primeiro de acordo com uma variável ASP.NET Razor C#.

```
<select id="MeetingFrequency" name="MeetingFrequency">
   <option value="0" selected disabled>Selecionar</option>
   <option value="SEMANAL">Semanal</option>
   <option value="MENSAL"> Mensal</option>
   <option value="BIMESTRAL" >Bimestral</option>
   <option value="TRIMESTRAL">Trimestral</option>
   <option value="QUADRIMESTRAL">Quadrimestral</option>
   <option value="SEMESTRAL">Semestral</option>
   <option value="ANUAL">Anual</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Como assim selecionar um valor de acordo com uma variável?

Comment: Bom ė um valor que vem do banco. Mas ja fiz de uma forma que funcinou

Comment: Conseguiu resolver ? da onde vem as informações, poderia colocar a lógica toda na sua pergunta!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom uma vez eu utilizei algo parecido com isso, vê se te ajuda!

```
@{  
bool[] select = new bool[2];
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
select[i] = false;
}
if(model.valor != null)
 switch (model.valor.ToString())
{
 case "SEMANAL": select[0] = true; break;
 case "MENSAL": select[1] = true; break;
 }
 }
}
<select id="MeetingFrequency" name="MeetingFrequency">
<option value="0"selected disabled>Selecionar</option>
<option value="SEMANAL"selected=@select[0]>Semanal</option>
<option value="MENSAL" selected=@select[1]> Mensal</option>
</select>
```

Da uma adaptada para sua necessidade

Answer (score 2):

Para manter um value *default* no componente `<select>` você deve utilizar a propriedade `<selected>` no `<option>`

Utilize dessa mandeia!

```
<option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
```

Veja na primeira linha de opção do seu componente `<select>` você já esta utilizando a propriedade `<selected>` por isso ele vem selecionado!

[Veja Exemplo](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option_selected)

Answer (score 2):

Pode ser feito com Razor através do **DropDownListFor** e pelo **SelectList**.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Variavel, new SelectList(Model.ListaVariavel, "Value", "Text", Model.Variavel), "Selecione")
```

No código, caso `model.Variavel` tenha valor, ele irá setar o valor para você. Caso precise de outro valor, coloque no `Model.Variavel` (terceiro parâmetro do selectlist)

Sugiro que veja sobre [SelectList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553(v=vs.108).aspx) e sobre [DropDownListFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev15.query?appId=Dev15IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor%60%602);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

Caso seja necessário, me fale e coloco um exemplo prático para você.